# overhead of using local http calls

Tags: http, api, rest

I'm developing a [wrapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_pattern) around an existent RESTful API. I basically have to do some preprocessing, calling the underlying API, and some preprocessing, with a little bit of cache in the middle. The API is specially designed for RESTful access via http.

My question is, should I refactor the API so I can invoke it via code, or should I make local http calls to it. This second option seems nice since it increases decoupling, but I'm afraid that creating the http requests / responses can seriously affect performance. I've heard though that [couchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) does something like that (its api is RESTful and accessed via http).

Comment: @skaffman I wouldn't have asked the question if I could measure it. Refactoring the API so that I can make a direct call is a tedious work that I'm trying to avoid by getting feedback from people who have done something similar to what I'm asking

Answer (score 5):

No one can answer this for you, as it will depend hugely on how your current RESTful API is implemented.  For example, you can write a relatively short C program that will listen on a socket and handle HTTP requests - if it does RESTful things in response to the different HTTP methods then it's an implementation of a RESTful API and can have very very little overhead over just calling the underlying functions directly (without HTTP).  On the other hand, you can write your program as this bloated, heavy Java EE monster - in that case, the overhead may be quite large.

Thus, skaffman was correct to say "Measure it and see" - this really is the only way to get a meaningful answer.

All that said, if you are asking this question, odds are good that you're not really facing a Google-scale problem, so if the refactoring is going to be a lot of work and just intercepting HTTP requests is easy for you then I'd suggest you first get the functionality you need with the HTTP wrapper and only once you have a working product start worrying about performance optimization.

Answer (score 2):

Look at section 5.1.6 in the [REST Dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) about layered systems.  What you are actually describing fits very nicely into this idea of a layered architecture.  Effectively you are building a HTTP proxy that will intercept the incoming requests, do some work and then and then pass it along to the next layer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd refactor it. You used to have some set of functionality exposed by a RESTful API. You've now got a set of functionality exposed by a RESTful API and by your wrapper. You should refactor the code so that it can do both. It should be easy if your code is reasonably well organized.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, err on the side of doing less work. Write the wrapper and test it. Refactor if you have to.